# Please can you check my Groovy 1.5 script for any obvious errors, It appears the wbs_elem value is not being assinged

Tags: groovy, salesforce, inline, boomi

I'm trying to take an input value in_company_code and use a switch to assign a mask depending on the value. This is what i've written, there are no obvious errors form my IDE, but when i run the script it appears wbs_elem isn't outputted at all, with no errors

```
switch(in_company_code){
case 1000:
wbs_elem = 'W' + in_wbs_elem;
break;

case 2000:
wbs_elem = 'U' + in_wbs_elem;
break;

case 3000:
wbs_elem = 'M' + in_wbs_elem;
break;
}
```

I've tried running the script in an online compiler, assigning values to the variables that are assinged in the interface by boomi. I expected to see for my input value of 3000, i would see Min_wbs_elem.

Comment: I see no `return`s in your code, only assignments.

Comment: There is an example switch in the boomi documentation that also has no returns, it looks nearly identical, could it be related to the input values being defined as Characters in boomi and perhaps the concatination is failing? If the concatination fails would it return a null value as a default? in_company_code(1000, 2000, 3000) comes as a text value from SF. Would the case statements be expecting an integer here?

Comment: print the class of the `in_company_code` out like `println in_company_code.getClass()` to see if the case-constants match it

Comment: it was expecting a string i'm guessing, i've written the cases as int above, re-written like this ;

`switch(in_company_code){
case '1000':
wbs_elem = 'W' + in_wbs_elem;
break;

case '2000':
wbs_elem = 'U' + in_wbs_elem;
break;

case '3000':
wbs_elem = 'M' + in_wbs_elem;
break;
}`
and it's now working! Every day is a learning day..